# Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Ultimo_Helper_Data' not found in /home/archtraders/stationerypoint/app/Mage.php on line 547

Tags: magento-1.9

I am having error when i try to open my [website](http://stationerypoint.com.au/).

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Ultimo_Helper_Data' not found 
in /home/archtraders/stationerypoint/app/Mage.php on line 547
```

Answer (score 2):

This message means that Magento don't see custom module Helper or module itself.
There are most common cases for this issue:

1) Module config is broken. Search `Ultimo/etc/config.xml` file, copy all content and use http://www.xmlvalidation.com/ to validate it's content

2) Module config does'n contain `<helpers>` section
it should look like

```
<helpers>
    <neklo_abtesting>
        <class>NAME-OF-MODULE-VENDOR-HERE_Ultimo_Helper</class>
    </neklo_abtesting>
</helpers>
```

and be placed inside "`<global>`" section.

3) Module is disabled or removed. Search folder app/etc/modules for file that contain "Ultimo" in name. And check it's content. 
it should contain line

```
<active>true</active>
```

If file doesn's exists, or contain line

```
<active>false</active>
```

then search all your files in `app/` folder, which contain next line

`Mage::helper("Ultimo")`  or `Mage::helper('ultimo')`

and replace it with

```
Mage::helper('core')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have compilation enabled, trying disabling or re-compiling in System, Tools, Compilation.

Check config.xml code of ultimo module

```
<global>
    <helpers>
        <ultimo><!-- class group -->
            <class>Namesapce_Module_Helper</class><!-- class prefix -->
        </ultimo>
    </helpers>
</global>
```

Also check helper class is available

```
<?php
class Namesapce_Module_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

If your module group name as shown in above code is **ultimo**

You can use

```
Mage::helper('ultimo');
```

It seems group name "ultimo" is different. So it will checking helper class but doesn't find it.So it will trigger helper class not found.

It helpful to you.